# Have QGraphicsItem receive ALL mouse moves?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a subclass of QGraphicsItem. By default, QGraphicsItem only receives mouseMoveEvents if the pointer is within the boundingRect of the item AND a mousePressEvent has also happened.

I want this subclass to receive ALL mouseMoveEvents that occur within the QGraphicsScene that it's a member of (preferably in item coordinates). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use `QGraphicsItem::grabMouse()` to ensure that you get all mouse events. If you do so, then [Qt promises the following](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#grabMouse):

> This item will receive all mouse events for the scene until any of the
> following events occurs:
>
> - The item becomes invisible
> - The item is removed from the scene
> - The item is deleted
> - The item call ungrabMouse()
> - Another item calls grabMouse(); the item will regain the mouse grab when the other item calls ungrabMouse().

Comment: Is there any way for more than one QGraphicsItem to receive mousemove events at the same time?

Comment: Without more details, I couldn't say what the best way of doing that might be. What you're trying is sounding increasingly hacky, though. Perhaps you should take a step back and ask a new question about whatever it is that you're ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically I want to have a bunch of autonomous agent-type things that react to the position of the mouse pointer.

Comment: I would subclass QGraphicsScene and re-implement `QGraphicsScene:mouseMoveEvent` to dispatch as you require.